# State of module support in VS 2017

Tags: c++, module, visual-studio-2017

Regarding Visual Studio 2017's C++ module support -- Is the support good enough such that developers can start converting their code bases to use modules?

I'm interested in refactoring my toy game engine to use modules. I've been reading conflicting info, online, about the status of this feature in VS2017, so I don't want to embark on the change if the feature is buggy or incomplete.

My main motivation for switching to modules is to do away with god damn header files.

Comment: Just wait until you start cursing all of the damn modules you have to import...

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and tried some tests for adding modules. Nope, this is not, at all, ready. I can't even get the simplest program to compile in the IDE. I have the lastest version (15.9.3, as of this writing).

This is one of the tutorials I tried, for example:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/05/cpp-modules-in-visual-studio-2017/